# Using vb script like a .bat file

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a vb script that will 
1. open the windows command line
2. change the directory to the location of the vb script itself, then 
3. change directory to go 1 more folder in

```
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "%~dp0"

WshShell.Run "cd nextfolder"
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: So.... you wrote this script. How did you execute it, and what happened?

Comment: Error: the system cannot find the file specified.. so I'm guessing the special character `%~dp0` is not valid here the same way I would use `cd %~dp0` in the command line, so I guess I'm looking for the correct way to use it here

Comment: You answered half of my question. Let me elaborate. Did you create this script as a file? Did you try to run the file? From where? A power shell prompt? Or from somewhere else? Not much information here...

Comment: Sorry- I wrote this in windows notepad, saved it script.vbs, then double clicked that file to run it

Comment: Wha tis `%~dp0` supposed to represent?

Comment: @lurker OP pointed in the title that `%~dp0` supposed to be evaluated as in .bat file.

Comment: @omegastripes yes I saw that the OP said it was used on the command line. But I am not sure what it represents as I said.

Comment: @lurker the representation is defined in bat/cmd syntax (i. e. [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)), or did you mean something else?

Comment: @omegastripes nope, it was really that simple a question. I wasn't familiar with that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /k cd nextfolder"
```

See `cmd /?`. `cd` is an internal command of cmd.exe.

and

```
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = wscript.path
```

See Help

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw3e6ehs(v=vs.84).aspx